# count ruby regular expression match

Tags: arrays, ruby, count

i was looking for count/length of my array.
matches aip then count =4 matches bip count =5 
these counts may vary everytime , those values for hosts will may be 3 to some n. so i was trying to call from length.

```
hosts = ["aip1,aip2,aip3,aip4","bip1,bip2,bip3,bip4,bip5"]

if ! hosts.nil?
  hosts.each do|d|
  if d.match(/^aip/)
      name = "a"
    else
      name = "b"
    end
```

i tried like this ,was not working for me , is there any better way i can try. to get count.

```
i was using counts = Hash.new(0)
hosts.each { |count| counts[count] += 1 }
```

i was trying to get exactly was , if match regexp aip then count = 4 or else count have to get 5(i have 5 bip's)
these count numbers will change everytime.
using ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux] version ruby

Comment: Are you generating the array of strings, or does it come to you that way?

Comment: Readers should not have to try to deduce your question by studying your code. Please edit to explain, in words, at the beginning, what you are trying to do. Also, whenever you give an example (`hosts` here) please show your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're trying to do and it almost seems like you're asking about an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

I'd recommend using something like this to break down the array of strings:

```
hosts = ["aip1,aip2,aip3,aip4","bip1,bip2,bip3,bip4,bip5,....."]

hash = hosts.map { |s| [ s[0], s.split(',') ] }.to_h
# => {"a"=>["aip1", "aip2", "aip3", "aip4"],
#     "b"=>["bip1", "bip2", "bip3", "bip4", "bip5", "....."]}
```

At this point `hash` makes it easy to find things out:

```
hash.keys # => ["a", "b"]

hash['a'] # => ["aip1", "aip2", "aip3", "aip4"]
hash['a'].size # => 4
```

And even determine `count`:

```
count = hash.values.map(&:size).reduce(&:+) # => 10
```

which breaks down to:

```
count = hash.values      # => [["aip1", "aip2", "aip3", "aip4"], ["bip1", "bip2", "bip3", "bip4", "bip5", "....."]]
            .map(&:size) # => [4, 6]
            .reduce(&:+) # => 10
```

If you're using Ruby 2.4+ you could use:

```
count = hash.values.sum { |i| i.size } # => 10
```